# A very strange puzzle of total differentiation

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Can't understand this strange puzzle.

Let $f(x_{1},x_{2})=x_{1}x_{2}$.

$\frac{df}{dx_{1}}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}\frac{dx_{2}}{dx_{1}}=x_{2}+x_{1}\frac{dx_{2}}{dx_{1}}$

$\int\frac{df}{dx_{1}}dx_{1}=\int\left(x_{2}+x_{1}\frac{dx_{2}}{dx_{1}}\right)dx_{1}$

$f(x_{1},x_{2})=\int x_{2}dx_{1}+\int x_{1}dx_{2}+c=2x_{1}x_{2}+c=x_{1}x_{2}?????$

What on earth has happened here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent variables, $\frac{d x_2}{ d x_1}=0$.

Comment: I am assuming they depend upon each other. That's when we need to talk about total differentiation any way.

Comment: If $x_2\equiv x_2(x_1)$ then $\int x_2\,dx_1$ does not equal $x_1 x_2$. You're also trying to do $\int x\cdot (df(x)/dx) dx=\int x\cdot df(x)$.

Comment: You're right! I did a silly thing. $\int x_{2}dx_{1}$ does not equal $x_{1}x_{2}$.

Comment: But this: $\int x\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx=\int x\cdot df(x)$. When does it hold and when doesn't it hold?

Comment: The latter is nothing but a shorthand notation for the former. You couldn't evaluate such an (Riemann) integral.

Comment: So $\int x\cdot\frac{df(x)}{dx}dx=\int x\cdot df(x)$ can only be done when $x\in\mathbb{R}$, right?